# how to disable the link in Colorbox iframe?

Tags: javascript, colorbox

```
<a class='iframe' href="delete.php" onClick="chkDel()">
```

I have use the iframe with Colorbox,
After click the link , i would to popup a confirm box like the code:

```
function chkDel(){ 
if(!confirm("delete?")){
//how to stay in the current state? 
//and do not run the delete page
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return false if the user cancels. Returning false will prevent the execution.

```
function chkDel(){ 
    if(!confirm("delete?")){
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can even do it in one line inside the onClick attribute.

```
onClick="return confirm('Are you sure about deleting this?');"
```